# Airflow: get messages from Kafka

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, airflow

I try get messages from Kafka in Airflow with `python-kafka` package.
Just in Python script it works. But in Airflow I have this messages from Kafka Consumer. And don't have messages from Kafka.

```
[2020-09-07 17:51:08,046] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-09-07 17:51:08,046] {parser.py:166} DEBUG - Processing response MetadataResponse_v1
[2020-09-07 17:51:08,047] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-09-07 17:51:08,047] {conn.py:1071} DEBUG - <BrokerConnection node_id=2 host=10.1.25.112:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('10.1.25.112', 9092)]> Response 28 (55.747270584106445 ms): MetadataResponse_v1(brokers=[(node_id=2, host='10.1.25.112', port=9092, rack=None), (node_id=3, host='10.1.25.113', port=9092, rack=None), (node_id=1, host='10.1.25.111', port=9092, rack=None)], controller_id=1, topics=[(error_code=0, topic='dev.tracking.nifi.rmsp.monthly.flow.downloading', is_internal=False, partitions=[(error_code=0, partition=0, leader=3, replicas=[3], isr=[3])])])
[2020-09-07 17:51:08,048] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-09-07 17:51:08,047] {cluster.py:325} DEBUG - Updated cluster metadata to ClusterMetadata(brokers: 3, topics: 1, groups: 0)
[2020-09-07 17:51:08,048] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-09-07 17:51:08,048] {fetcher.py:296} DEBUG - Stale metadata was raised, and we now have an updated metadata. Rechecking partition existance
[2020-09-07 17:51:08,048] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-09-07 17:51:08,048] {fetcher.py:299} DEBUG - Removed partition TopicPartition(topic='dev.tracking.nifi.rmsp.monthly.flow.downloading', partition=(0,)) from offsets retrieval
[2020-09-07 17:51:08,049] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-09-07 17:51:08,048] {fetcher.py:247} DEBUG - Could not find offset for partition TopicPartition(topic='dev.tracking.nifi.rmsp.monthly.flow.downloading', partition=(0,)) since it is probably deleted
[2020-09-07 17:51:08,107] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-09-07 17:51:08,107] {group.py:453} DEBUG - Closing the KafkaConsumer.
```

This error occurs when calling

```
        # Issue #1780
        # Recheck partition existence after after a successful metadata refresh
        if refresh_future.succeeded() and isinstance(future.exception, Errors.StaleMetadata):
            log.debug("Stale metadata was raised, and we now have an updated metadata. Rechecking partition existance")
            unknown_partition = future.exception.args[0]  # TopicPartition from StaleMetadata
            if self._client.cluster.leader_for_partition(unknown_partition) is None:
                log.debug("Removed partition %s from offsets retrieval" % (unknown_partition, ))
                timestamps.pop(unknown_partition)
```

Why I can't get topic leader?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide some more info on your problem / set up.
we cannot see the set up, for example are you using docker for Airflow? and local machine for Kafka?

   
Then some people might be able to help you out.